# How can I make my Android app appear in the list of apps used to share something?

Tags: android, button, share, highlighting

Ok, this is hard to explain, but this is what I don't know how to do:

Basically when you highlight text in Android, you are then given the option to share that piece of text. Therefore you just click on the share button in the menubar.

Now, how can make my app appear in that list of app which can be used to share the text?

Answer (score 2):

Create a activity YourActivtiy and register in manifest with action SEND mime type text/plan even you can handle image type as well by adding another intent filter.

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following `Intent Filter` to an activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="yourmimehere"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: I want to add, there is an official training in the android docs: http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to write this your manifest file

```
<activity android:name=".SomeActivity" >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="tsome mime here" />
</intent-filter>
```